# Meaning difference between two sentences using "to" and "for"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

What would be the meaning difference between these two sentences, using "to" in one case and "for" in another, is one wrong ? Please explain the difference.

> To all the joy we've shared and everything we've done !

or

> For all the joy we've shared and everything we've done !

Comment: The first one sounds like a toast (Let us drink to...). The second isn't a proper sentence either, but it could be the reason for a gift (This is to thank you for...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is subtle and somewhat based on context.  I don't think most native English speakers would put much thought into either one, nor notice much of a difference in meaning, if any.

> **To** all the joy we've shared and everything we've done!

The word "to" indicates that "all the joy we've shared..." is the recipient of something.  For instance if this phrase was used in a [toast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(honor)), it would be the recipient of the speaker's toast.

"Thank you all for joining me this New Years.  Let's have a toast!  **To all the joy we've shared and everything we've done!**"

> **For** all the joy we've shared and everything we've done!

The word "for" indicates that "all the joy we've shared..." is the reason we are doing something.  It is the same principle as the idiom "[for the love of God](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351296/what-exactly-does-for-the-love-of-god-mean)", which taken literally would mean the reason you are doing something is to receive God's love in return.

"Farewell everyone.  **For all the joy we've shared and everything we've done**, I thank you."